# Opposite of show in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to import all classes from a package except for one. You can import only one class from a package like for example: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show Text;`. But is there a way to import everything from flutter/material.dart except Text?

Comment: import 'lib' hide Text;